# Sublime Text 3 - snippet with csv scope?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

How do I define csv scope, so snippet would only apply to csv files?

I have this snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
access_${1:name},access_${1:name} user,model_${1:name},${2:base.group_user},1,0,0,0
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>ir.model.access</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.csv</scope>
    <description>Ir Model Access CSV</description>
</snippet>
```

But it does not show up in tab autocomplete. Also tried `source.csv`, same thing. If I remove `scope`, then it does show up, but then it is suggested on any type of file, which I don't want to.

Comment: What CSV package are you using for syntax highlighting?

Comment: Didn't use any. But now installed rainbow csv highlight and could just choose `rainbow1` scope for it. And it works now. Thanks for a hint :)